# Laravel Retrieve related model through pivot table

Tags: laravel-5

So i'm a bit confused with this situation, I have the current relations:
`User` hasmany `Favourite`
favourites references to a `Recipe` model
favourites is a pivot table but when I retrieve the favourites for a given user like:

> $user->favourites

i get the favourite with the pivot data, but I want to get the fields of the recipe

**Recipe.php**:

```
public function favourites()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Favourite');
}
```

**User.php**:

```
public function favourites()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Favourite');
}
```

**Favourite.php**:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}

public function recipes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe','recipe_id');
}
```

**EDIT** : **there was no problem at all, just needed to call:**

```
@foreach($user->favourites as $favourite)
    {{ $favourite->recipe->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your relation to Has Many Through instead of just has Many.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Recipe.php:

```
public function favourites()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Favourite', 'App\User');
}
```

User.php:

```
public function favourites()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Favourite', 'App\Receipe');
}
```

Favourite.php:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User','App\Receipe');
}
```

Comment: I got it working...nvm i'm actually very tired. I'll try your solution